# Is default(IntPtr) legal in an extern function?

Tags: c#, null, intptr

Let's say I have the following signature:

```
static extern void External(int foo, IntPtr bar);
```

I want to make it use defaults:

```
static extern void External(int foo = 10, IntPtr bar = default(IntPtr));
```

Is this valid? In C++, I would use the pointer to be 0 or null. In C#, it's not even clear if IntPtr is value or reference.

If I called my function manually, I would use `External(10, IntPtr.Zero);`. I guess my question is: Will `default(IntPtr)` have the same behavior as `IntPtr.Zero`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`IntPtr` is a value type, and its default is indeed `IntPtr.Zero`. So this will work as you expect.

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(v=vs.80).aspx) contains the following quote:

> For structs, it will return each member of the struct initialized to zero or null depending on whether they are value or reference types.

Since `IntPtr` is a struct, its members will be initialized to 0.